# encodeURI(JSON.stringify()) showing %255B in URL

Tags: javascript, urlencode, query-string, encodeuricomponent

I am trying to pass along a queryParam in Angular that consists of an array of objects as such `fooArray = [{foo: 'bar', foo: false}, {foo: 'bar', foo: false}]`. In the URL queryParam I am receiving the following: %255B when using `encodeURI(JSON.stringify(this.fooArray))`

I have tried using encodeURI(JSON.stringify()) to encode the array into the queryParam and JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent()) to retrieve the param

`fooArray = [{foo: 'bar', foo: false}, {foo: 'bar', foo: false}]`

`fooParam: encodeURI(JSON.stringify(this.fooArray))`

`JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params["fooParam"]))`

Comment: Pay attention that you second keys (`foo: false` ) are overriding the first (`foo: 'bar'`)

Comment: `encodeURI(JSON.stringify([{foo: 'bar', foo: false}, {foo: 'bar', foo: false}]))` gives me `"%5B%7B%22foo%22:false%7D,%7B%22foo%22:false%7D%5D"` (Chrome). It sounds to me like you're double-encoding it, since if you pass that through **again**, the `%` encodes (correctly) to `%25`.

Comment: Could you add a little more context? E.g. where are you using your query params? In a `router.navigate`? If so, you do not need to encode anything as angular is doing that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're double-encoding the URL. This:

```
encodeURI(JSON.stringify([{foo: 'bar', foo: false}, {foo: 'bar', foo: false}]))
```

results in

```
"%5B%7B%22foo%22:false%7D,%7B%22foo%22:false%7D%5D"
```

If you call `encodeURI` on it again, you get

```
"%255B%257B%2522foo%2522:false%257D,%257B%2522foo%2522:false%257D%255D"
```

...because `%` is encoded as `%25`.

Two notes:

1. You should encode it only once. Perhaps you're passing the string to something that will already URI-encode it for you? If so, don't use `encodeURI`.
2. Usually, you want `encodeURIComponent`, not `encodeURI` (because usually you're encoding just a component of hte URI, not the entire thing).

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this problem, and what I discovered was that somewhere along the chain of my code, I was running `.toString()`, which runs a `encodeURI` on my string/url.

I was essentially double encoding my search params without knowing it.
If you're running `.toString()`  on an instance of [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) or [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString) class, then you don't need to manually run `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`

### Testing For Double Encoding

A quick way to learn if you're double encoding a string is to setup a quick example test run in your javascript developer tools. Visualizing this help me a lot:

```js
const searchParams1 = '?status=open&created_by=bobby&date';
const url1 = "http://example.com/" + searchParams1;
const searchParamsString1 = new URL(exampl1).toString() // NOTE: `toString()` runs encode on the string for you!

const searchParams2 = '?status=open&date_filter={"by":"created","qualifier":"between","value":["2022/04/01","2022/04/02"]}';
const example2 = "http://example.com/" + searchParams2;
const searchParamsString2 = new URL(example2).toString();

// encoded 1x
searchParamsString2 ===
  "http://example.com/?status=open&date_filter={%22by%22:%22created%22,%22qualifier%22:%22between%22,%22value%22:[%222022/04/01%22,%222022/04/02%22]}";

// encoded 2x (visual)
const example2DoubleEncoded = encodeURI(
  "http://example.com/?status=open&date_filter={%22by%22:%22created%22,%22qualifier%22:%22between%22,%22value%22:[%222022/04/01%22,%222022/04/02%22]}"
);
example2DoubleEncoded ==="http://example.com/?status=open&date_filter=%7B%2522by%2522:%2522created%2522,%2522qualifier%2522:%2522between%2522,%2522value%2522:%5B%25222022/04/01%2522,%25222022/04/02%2522%5D%7D";
```